# IPad Web App- Can't Get Landscape Splash Screen To Show

Tags: ipad, landscape, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm trying to convert a web page to look like a native app. I've got the icon to show and the portrait splash screen to show but the landscape splash screen will not. Here are some my meta tags-

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="images/splash_tall.jpg" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="images/splash_wide.jpg" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icon.png" />
```

The images are 768x1004 (portrait) and 1024x748 (portrait). Anyone see anything off?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it matters, but update your images to .png and update your link references to....

```
<!-- iPad Portrait 768x1004 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" href="spash-1004.png" />
<!-- iPad Landscape 1024x748 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="spash-1024.png" />
```

Comment: The orientation media query does the trick. Just add media="(orientation: landscape)" to your landscape <link>s